# OnClick with arrow function giving re-render React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm having a problem that I've already search and nothing helped me..

What happens is: every time that i click in the `DropdownItem` it gives a re-render, looks that the screen give reload.. I've saw that this is because i'm using the onclick with arrow function, but i dont know as to use without and not give re-render...

Someone help me ?

```js
<NameFilter>Country</NameFilter>
<DropdownStyled 
   defaultText='Select a Country'
   value={this.props.clear === true ? "" : valueCountry}>
   {filters.country.map(i => 
       <DropdownItem onClick={() => this.props.handleFilter("country", "countryStatus", i)}
          itemText={i} value={i}/>)}
</DropdownStyled>
```

HandleFilter:

```js
toFilter = (nameFilter, nameFilterStatus, valueFilter) => {
  this.setState({
    [nameFilter]: valueFilter,
    [nameFilterStatus]: valueFilter
  });
}
```

In other words: it re-render all components, after click..

Comment: Please reformat your code and show me how this.props.handleFilter looks like.

Comment: @ZeroCho fine, already updated

Comment: Can you show us the code for `DropdownItem` ? does it have a link <a> by any chance?

Comment: is it a problem that is reloading the page, or re-rendering?

Comment: re-render all components, after click

Comment: once `setState` on parent component finishes on rerendering parent component all child component are updated(calling `shouldComponentUpdate()` and then running `render()` for them). so it's expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Instead of inline arrow function use simple function
   onChange={this.toFilter("country", "countryStatus", i)}

// Method declaration - Use arrow function here
// Note: Double arrow here:-
   toFilter = (nameFilter, nameFilterStatus, valueFilter) => () => {
     this.setState({
       [nameFilter]: valueFilter,
       [nameFilterStatus]: valueFilter
     });
   }
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: I have a question, why you've used double arrow function?

Comment: Inline arrow functions in render (anti-pattern) will trigger re-render therefore curried arrow function.. for in-depth explanation - https://medium.com/@machnicki/handle-events-in-react-with-arrow-functions-ede88184bbb

Answer (score 0):

Every time you use `setState` it will trigger a re-render after updating the state.
If you want to prevent this try using [shouldComponentUpdate](https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/using_should_component_update.html)

Comment: But, how i use that in the parent component ?

The parent component is where i have the `toFilter`

Comment: Not sure I follow, but you have to set the `shouldComponentUpdate` method on the parent component, since you are calling `setState` on the parent component, hence, triggering the re-render